# A good reason why gods cant interact with the material world

Tags: magic, gods

I have a pantheon in my world that I feel would want to get involved in the adventures I have my protagonists go on. Gods in my case are just very powerful beings who mastered their specific abilities to become "gods" to those below them in skill and power. I need a reason to keep them out of my story when it comes to battles that they can obviously handle to let the protagonists do their thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A Truce**

If one gets involved, all get involved and nobody wants the chaos and destruction of a bunch of gods at war thus all agreed to stay out of it upon pain of destruction with all the gods banding to destroy the offender.

As such, they don't get involved directly but continue their games through proxies and manipulation.